# Why does sphinx-build (installed with Python 3.8.6) use Python 3.8.2?

Tags: python-3.x, homebrew, python-import, python-sphinx, pyenv

When doing imports in `conf.py`, I got complaints from autodoc when running `sphinx-build source/ build/`:

> WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module '<my_module>' from module '<my_project>'; the following exception was raised:
> No module named 'pandas'

Note that unlike in many SO questions referring to this kind of error, the problem here is not my own project/module which **is** found!
Instead the pandas dependency isn't.

I made sure the Python version I used to install sphinx (Python 3.8.6) has pandas installed and added `print(sys.version)` to the `conf.py` file to discover that sphinx actually uses a different version (3.8.2)!

What's more I never actively installed version 3.8.2 (I have 3.8.5 and 3.8.6 through brew and 3.8.6 through pyenv)

When running `make html` instead the correct Python version is used.
So what is the issue with the `sphinx-build`?

Comment: How do you run `conf.py`? Is it `python conf.py` or `./conf.py` and the file starts with a shebang?

Comment: Besides printing `sys.version`, you can also try printing `sys.executable`.

Comment: I added this, I am indirectly running `conf.py` via `sphinx-build source/ build/`

Comment: I am importing my package to check the version number to set the `release` variable. That way I only have to change it in one place

Comment: To actually answer your question, we probably need a proper [mcve].

Comment: @mzjn I don't hat much time for this now, but as pointed out by @fonini printing `sys.executable` showed that `sphinx-build` uses  `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3` while `which python` gives me `/Users/mrclng/.pyenv/shims/python`!

Comment: With pyenv, you should `pyenv which python` instead of just `which python` in order to get the path to the Python executable that will run when you type `python` at the command line.

Comment: Do [`pyenv versions`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/COMMANDS.md#pyenv-versions) to see which versions are installed and active. See also [`pyenv local`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/COMMANDS.md#pyenv-local).

Comment: `pyenv which versions` -> `/Users/mrclng/.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/bin/python`
`pyenv versions` ->
`system
* 3.8.6 (set by /Users/mrclng/.pyenv/version)
  3.9.0`